# String retornando vazia

Tags: c#, json, stream, arquivo-zip

Estou tentando fazer com que eu entre no arquivo .zip, selecione um arquivo único chamado de `mcmod.info` e salve para uma `MemoryStream` temporária.

Segui como base [esse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967864/how-to-read-data-from-a-zip-file-without-having-to-unzip-the-entire-file) no StackOverflow, mas quando eu faço a leitura da `var ms = new MemoryStream()` usando um `var texto = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();` e faço com que use `MessageBox.Show(texto);` a MessageBox retorna uma String vazia.

```
  ZipFile zf = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\big-reactors.zip");
  ZipEntry ze = zf["mcmod.info"];

  MemoryStream memory_stream = new MemoryStream();
  ze.Extract(memory_stream);

  TextReader text_reader = new StreamReader(memory_stream);
  string json = text_reader.ReadToEnd();

   MessageBox.Show(json);
```

No arquivo `mcmod.info` contém tipo [json](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/FML/wiki/FML-mod-information-file), essas linhas:

```
[
  {
    "modid": "BigReactors",
    "name": "Big Reactors",
    "description": "Adds large, multiblock power generation machines to Minecraft. Compatible with Redstone Flux (RF) power.",
    "version": "0.4.3A",
    "mcversion": "1.7.10",
    "url": "http://www.big-reactors.com",
    "updateUrl": "",
    "authorList": ["ErogenousBeef"],
    "credits": "powercrystals, skyboy, King_Lemming, & Calclavia for example code",
   "logoFile": "",
   "screenshots": [],
   "dependencies": [
        "MinecraftForge", "CoFHCore"
       ] 
   }
]
```

Já fiz um código que faça a Deserialização dele, mas o foco no momento é que eu tenha retorno da `Stream.ReadToEnd();`

Usei isso para deserializar:

```
public class MCModInfo
{
    public string modid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string mcversion { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string updateUrl { get; set; }
    public List<string> authorList { get; set; }
    public string credits { get; set; }
    public string logoFile { get; set; }
    public List<string> screenshots { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public List<string> requiredMods { get; set; }
    public List<string> dependencies { get; set; }
    public List<string> dependants { get; set; }
    public bool useDependencyInformation { get; set; }
}

public class MCModInfo_Parser
{
    public MCModInfo Deserialize(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MCModInfo>(json);
    }

    public string Serialize(MCModInfo mcmodinfo)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mcmodinfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri! Apos a criação da MemoryStream eu tenho que fazer com que ela volte do começo.

```
memory_stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```